# Please Help Me adding a module in magento

Tags: magento

I create a module in Magento 2.3.1 add this in my magento project but is not working.All the menu option of Admin dashboard has been disabled.
Please Help!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First Create a Custom Module From ref. Link

> https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-modules/

Then in CMD Run Command 
`magento module:enable module_name`
after run this command
`php bin\magento setup:upgrade`
Then Flush The Cache
`php bin\magento c:f`